# Using different ADO.NET providers dynamically with Entity Framework

Tags: .net, entity-framework, ado.net

My application can work with different databases like SQL Server, MySQL, Oracle, PostgreSQL or SQLite. It knows how to load the relevant ADO.NET assembly (its DLL file name is known) and find the `DbProviderFactory` type in it. This factory gives me everything I need to work with the database connection on the plain ADO.NET level.

Entering Entity Framework. I used to use my own O/RM but want to replace it with EF 6 Code First. My own O/RM simply generated SQL and ran it with the `DbCommand` class. EF seems to do a lot more and require special configuration. I can't add assembly references to any supported database client provider and require deploying all those files. I need a solution that loads assemblies at runtime dynamically and finds its way from there. Then, depending on what database shall be used, I only deploy the DLLs required for that.

For now that doesn't work yet. I get the error message for PostgreSQL:

> System.NotSupportedException: Unable to determine the provider name for
>   provider factory of type 'Npgsql.NpgsqlFactory'. Make sure that the
>   ADO.NET provider is installed or registered in the application config.

This happens when I try to add an entity to a `DbSet`. The database server connection has already been opened and my schema installation is done. (I don't use EF migrations and I don't use connection strings but open the connection myself when needed.) I know that I haven't added any specific configuration to the app.config file. I don't like that file altogether and would like to avoid using it completely.

Is there some API that I could use to register anything required for EF? I have the type and an instance of the Npgsql provider, for example. Could I just pass that to some EF method so that it will use it?